TRL SFTTrainer clarification on truncation
I am currently finetuning LLama models using SFTTrainer in huggingface. However, I came up with a question, I can not answer through the documentations (atleast, it is a bit ambigious).
My dataset contains samples from 20 tokens to 5k tokens.
Currently I am using a max_seq_length=512, and packing=True.
However, what is unclear to me is, what happens with samples with >512 tokens. Are they simple truncated?
If yes, is there any simple option to split them, rather to truncate them?
